# Is it possible to store array of values in cookies during for loop in JSP?

Tags: jsp

Is it possible to store array of values in cookies during for loop.If yes then how and if no then how can i sort this problem to store array elements in cookie??

Following is code am trying:

```
<%
    String check[] = request.getParameterValues("chk");
    String a[] = " ";
    if (check != null) {
%>
<h4 style="color:white">
<%
    for (int i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
        out.println(check[i]);
        a[i] = check[i];
    }
    Cookie c1 = new Cookie(chks, check[i]);
    response.addCookie(c1);
}
%>
</h4>

<a href="basket.jsp" style="text-decoration: none;color:white">proceed</a>
```

Comment: Following is code am trying: <%
String check[]=request.getParameterValues("chk");
String a[]=" ";
if(check != null)
{%>
<h4 style="color:white">
<%
for(int i=0;i<check.length;i++)
{
out.println(check[i]);
a[i]=check[i];
}
Cookie c1=new Cookie(chks,check[i]);
response.addCookie(c1);
}
%>
</h4>
<a href="basket.jsp" style="text-decoration: none;color:white">proceed</a>

Comment: I have added the code in the question itself in future do the same to your posts instead of adding in the comment

Comment: does this even compile? what errors do you get? what does it do versus what you think it should do? need more info.

Comment: I'm really thinking that `String a[] = " ";` is a syntax error.